# Why hash in Node.js give different result with same character?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So i was try to hash `¤` character in node js, with this function
`crypto.createHash('md5').update('¤', 'ascii').digest('hex')`
give md5 hash

> f37c6f3896b2c85fbbd01ae32e47b43f

and using `Buffer`

`crypto.createHash('md5').update(new Buffer('¤', 'ascii').toString()).digest('hex')`

give result like this:

> 9b759040321a408a5c7768b4511287a6

I tried to debug `Hash.update()` to take a look inside but i can't it seems hard compiled.

Why `crypto` encoding method is different with `Buffer`? what makes it different?

Comment: Even if `new Buffer('¤', 'ascii').toString() == '¤'`, you are missing the second argument to `update`. Or if you intended to pass the raw binary data and not let `update` deal with the encoding, then you probably shouldn't have called `.toString()` but passed the buffer instead.

Comment: @Bergi thank you for your reply, and i just realized, that buffer of that character in utf-8 is [194,164] while in ascii is [164]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

crypto is encoding the same way as buffers do, so let’s ignore it for now. Here’s a simplification of the issue:

```
const text = '¤';
const b1 = Buffer.from(text, 'ascii');
const b2 = Buffer.from(b1.toString());
```

b1 and b2 aren’t the same bytes. b1 is [0xa4], which doesn’t really make much sense as 0xa4 isn’t part of ASCII; [Node is using the same code to encode strings as ASCII and Latin-1 here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/b2b9d11a14c85296f2435894bcc43b94c10dce07/src/string_bytes.cc#L333-L334). I don’t know if that’s for compatibility or performance reasons or what, but it seems like a bad idea, results in values for which `Buffer.from(s, 'ascii')` is different from `Buffer.from(Buffer.from(s, 'ascii').toString('ascii'), 'ascii')`, and does not appear to be documented anywhere.

In modern versions of Node, the default encoding is UTF-8, so `b1.toString()` will try to interpret `0xa4` as UTF-8, fail, and produce a replacement character (�) instead, encoded as [0xef, 0xbf, 0xbd]. In non-modern versions of Node, it will do an environment-dependent wrong thing instead of a consistent wrong thing.

You can make your operations give the same result by passing a buffer instead of a UTF-8 encoding of a buffer:

```
crypto.createHash('md5').update(new Buffer('¤', 'ascii')).digest('hex')
```

(note how `.toString()` is removed)

but correct code, able to hash any sequence of Unicode codepoints, would use UTF-8 instead.

```
crypto.createHash('md5').update('¤', 'utf8').digest('hex')
crypto.createHash('md5').update(Buffer.from('¤', 'utf8')).digest('hex')
```

Comment: Why community wiki? This is a perfectly fine answer.

Comment: @Bergi: Hey, I wouldn't CW bad answers either! =D It’s actually about being tired of getting rep notifications.

Comment: Ah, I just learned to live with the constant green pin in the top bar, never clicking it. The count went to 5 digits before I fat-fingered it recently :D

Comment: Thank you for your great explanation.